# Download File From SharePoint 365

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365

I'm using this code from [MSDN Web Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```cs
string remoteUri = "http://www.contoso.com/library/homepage/images/";
string fileName = "ms-banner.gif", myStringWebResource = null;
// Create a new WebClient instance.
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
// Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
Console.WriteLine("Downloading File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\" .......\n\n", fileName, myStringWebResource);
// Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource,fileName);     
Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\"", fileName, myStringWebResource);
Console.WriteLine("\nDownloaded file saved in the following file system folder:\n\t" + Application.StartupPath);
```

But I have coming across the error: 403 forbidden

Can someone Help me Put this working ?

Comment: Why type of authentication is the file you are downloading behind? Have you tried setting the `myWebClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("User","Pass");` for basic auth?

Comment: Have the same error after tried the Credentials !

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the same issue and tried the answer suggested by Vadim Gremyachev. However, it still kept giving 403 error. I added two extra  headers to force form based authentication like below:

```
client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
```

After this it started working. So the full code goes like below:

```
const string username = "username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
const string password = "password";
const string url = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/";
var securedPassword = new SecureString();
foreach (var c in password.ToCharArray()) securedPassword.AppendChar(c);
var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securedPassword);

DownloadFile(url,credentials,"/Shared Documents/Report.xslx");


private static void DownloadFile(string webUrl, ICredentials credentials, string fileRelativeUrl)
{
     using(var client = new WebClient())
     {
        client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
        client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
        client.Credentials = credentials;
        client.DownloadFile(webUrl, fileRelativeUrl);
     }  
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This error occurs since the request is not authenticated. In order to access resource in Office/SharePoint Online you could utilize [SharePointOnlineCredentials class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx) from [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35585) (*user credentials* flow).

The following example demonstrates how to download a file from SPO:

```
const string username = "username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
const string password = "password";
const string url = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/";
var securedPassword = new SecureString();
foreach (var c in password.ToCharArray()) securedPassword.AppendChar(c);
var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securedPassword);

DownloadFile(url,credentials,"/Shared Documents/Report.xslx");


private static void DownloadFile(string webUrl, ICredentials credentials, string fileRelativeUrl)
{
     using(var client = new WebClient())
     {
        client.Credentials = credentials;
        client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
        client.DownloadFile(webUrl, fileRelativeUrl);
     }  
}
```

Comment: i am getting 403 exception in above code. It is also notice that fileRelativeUrl should be path of local system where file will save.

Comment: The code is incorrect in use of fileRelativeURL when calling client.DownloadFile. Running this code results in similar 403 errors as OP reports. Not the best answer in that sense.

Comment: @Kris, thanks you for the constructive comment. The error indeed might occur since SharePoint also requires additional header to be present in the request: `X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED:f`.