# Microsoft Graph download file content returns 404

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I tried to download a file with Grpah API.

Tested with API browser,
https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer#

Ran following request, got list of file/folder item information,

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children

And for one of the file item, I was able to get item information.

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/items/_an_item_id

But following returns HTTP 404.

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/items/_an_item_id/content

What will be the cause for this symptom?

Comment: Did the `/content` request itself `404`, or did it redirect you (`302`) to a URL that then returned a `404`?

Comment: Thanks @Brad, yes, 302 returned first and then 404.  

And the found location is exactly the same is the "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl" information for the File Item.

Comment: @Brad, so is it because just the graph Explorer doesn't support the redirection?

I have authenticated my Azure registered app with Daemon mode, got Auth-Code. I tried to download the file in 'download url' with 'Bearer' HTTP header but it says 404.

How do you download a file from that link?

Comment: You mentioned daemon mode, does this mean you're targeting a OneDrive for Business account with an app-only token?

Comment: @Brad Not sure what's 'App-only' token but I tried "Daemon or Server Application to Web API" auth flow described here. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/
Example is here
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon

It basically uses Client Id and Client secret, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported to perform request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/items/<itemid>/content` endpoint via [Graph Explorer](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer#).

The request sent to `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/items/<itemid>/content` endpoint via Grath Explorer is issued as a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests). The server responds with `302-Redirect` but redirects are not allowed for preflighted requests due to [CORS behavior](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0).

Here is a workaround on how to download a file

The following *drive item* resource request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/items/<itemId>
```

returns `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` annotation which contains the actual link to file resource.

Once the drive item resource is retrieved, perform another GET request to url from `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` to return the actual file.

Comment: Thanks.

Strange but it seems it returns 404 for the download request if I use accesstoken by 'Daemon or Server Application' type,  written in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/

But If I use the Acces token from following auth flow, it gives me the content data.
https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm

The latter requires User-Login, and I login as a Global Admin user for a domain. The former requires no user login, because it's daemon.

Does the AccessToken type affect the behavior for the file download request?

Comment: @Locke I have the same issue (404) retrieving a file using  'App-only' token. Have you been able to download the file without user interaction?

Comment: @MartinoBordin I'm afraid no. I think it's because they have some level of authentication, and under lower authentication level, we can not do much things like downloading contents.

Comment: @Locke It's a shame we cannot download the contents using graph via "daemon authentication"...anyway I've been able to download it using sharepoint credentials and WebUrl returned by graph. Check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23687279/485732

Comment: @MartinoBordin Congrats. But the main purpose I wanted to use Daemon Auth. type was to minimize the user interaction, not needing password information per each users. I am not using that Daemon Auth. type now.

Comment: With my method I don't have any user interaction..I just set up a "system" account in sharepoint and use it in my "Daemon"

Comment: How would one go about downloading ``OneNote`` notebook if ``DriveItem`` does not expose ``file`` property or ``@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl`` property?

Comment: Nevermind my previous question. I looked up package resource type and this is what I found. DriveItems with the package facet do not include a folder or file facet but are conceptually similar to an item with a folder facet. Which explains lack of mimeType and file extension. My guess is that notebooks are not for offline use.

Comment: Vadim Gremyachev How can I get @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl for file version history  files?