# when redirecting to Microsoft sign in page getting cors issue for microsoft graph

Tags: php, azure, laravel-5, cors, microsoft-graph-api

I am developing laravel api and the UI is angularjs ,issue is when redirecting to Microsoft sign in page getting cors issue for microsoft graph,the issue is

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://reservations-api.nymblpro.com/coordinator/event. Redirect from
>   'https://reservations-api.nymblpro.com/coordinator/event' to
>   'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?state=cuSlE1…rect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Freservations-api.nymblpro.com%2Fcoordinator%2Fevent'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is
>   disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect.

I tried setting cors middleware still I am getting same issue.
my code is as follows:

```
public function get_microsoft_token(Request $request)
{
    $provider = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
        'clientId'                => 'fd482697-fd9f-46ac-ab3a-727e47517c8b',
        'clientSecret'            => 'WZOh3qLz7ZQyKemCQf3RsCF',
        'redirectUri'             => 'https://reservations-api.nymblpro.com/coordinator/event',
        'urlAuthorize'            => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
        'urlAccessToken'          => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token',
        'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
        'scopes'                  => 'openid calendars.readwrite'
    ]);
    if (!$request->has('code')) {
        return redirect($provider->getAuthorizationUrl());
    }
    else {
        $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
            'code' => $request->input('code')
        ]);
        return ($accessToken->getToken());
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388152/microsoft-graph-download-file-content-returns-404/40400293#40400293 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949492/cors-request-with-preflight-and-redirect-disallowed-workarounds/39728229#39728229 may be relevant

Comment: It would be helpful if you also posted the relevant part of your client JavaScript code that’s sending the request.

Comment: @sideshowbarker  here is the JavaScript                                                             '$scope.getTokenForCalender=function()
    {       
    var url="https://reservation-api.dev/coordinator/event";
        mainHTTPService.getData(url,globalService.getReqHeader())
            .then(function(result){  
           console.log("Token For Calender Integration - "+JSON.stringify(result)); 
            }, function(err){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
             alert("Error Occured....");
            });     
    }
 $scope.getTokenForCalender();
here err is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that your AngularJs application will call your Laravel application's api, which returns the authorization url, then your angularJs frontend will call this url in AJAX function. So this should be the criminal.

You can try to modify the code in your angularjs front end application, change something like `$http.get()` function to something like:

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Otherwise, you can try to use adal for js in your angularjs application. Refer to https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js for more info.

Comment: i was able to bypass this issue by directly redirecting to authorization signing page ,thanks @garry liu and sidesshowbarker