# After download the excel I'm getting the excel cannot open the file '(filename)'.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid

Tags: c#, excel, webclient

I have download the excel from office 365 share point and file is downloaded successfully and I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57574397/how-can-i-download-an-excel-file-from-sharepoint-server).

**What I edited ?**

**Logic 1 is I added**

I have used `httpClient` for downloading the excel from the office 365 share point and the excel is able to downloading to given path but that excel also getting the same king of error as I mentioned in this post.

```
private async Task SaveFile(string fileUrl, string pathToSave, string username, object securedPassword)
        {
            
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", ""+username+":"+securedPassword+"".ToString());
            var httpResult = await httpClient.GetAsync(fileUrl);
            var resultStream = await httpResult.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            var filePath = pathToSave;
            System.IO.FileStream fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
            resultStream.CopyTo(fileStream);

        }
```

Calling Method is

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
const string username = "kumar@xxxxx.com";
            const string password = "Welcome@1055";
            const string url = "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/files/my%20Files/excel%20folder";
            const string templocation = @"c:\Downloads\Sharepoint\Task.xlsx";
            var securedPassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (var c in password.ToCharArray()) securedPassword.AppendChar(c);
            var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securedPassword);

_ = SaveFile(url, templocation, username, securedPassword);

 }
```

**Logic 2 :**

This is the code of excel download

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
const string username = "kumar@xxxxx.com";
            const string password = "Welcome@1055";
            const string url = "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/files/my%20Files/excel%20folder";
            const string templocation = @"c:\Downloads\Sharepoint\Task.xlsx";
            var securedPassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (var c in password.ToCharArray()) securedPassword.AppendChar(c);
            var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securedPassword);

            DownloadFile(url, credentials, templocation);
}

private static void DownloadFile(string webUrl, ICredentials credentials, string fileRelativeUrl)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {

                client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
                client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
                client.Credentials = credentials;
                client.DownloadFile(webUrl, fileRelativeUrl);
            }
        }
```

Once excel downloaded successfully I'm trying to open that excel manually from the downloaded folder at that time I'm getting this error

```
Excel cannot open the file 'Task.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.
```

Example img :

[image: Excel error]

And I have changed the extension also (xls , csv) for testing but the result is same (getting the same kind of error)

And I have try to open that excel file using logic here also getting the same kind of error

Below is my code :

```
   public DataTable ReadExcel_tskmgmt(string fileName, string fileExt, string sstext)
        {
            fileExt = fileExt.ToLower();
            string conn = string.Empty;
            DataTable dtexcel = new DataTable();
            string ssssheetname = "-";
            
            try
            {
                if (fileExt.CompareTo(".csv") == 0)
                    conn = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited""", Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName));
                else if (fileExt.CompareTo(".xls") == 0)
                    conn = @"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HRD=Yes;IMEX=1';"; //for below excel 2007  
                else
                    conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"; //for above excel 2007  

                using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conn))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
//Getting error here                        
//Excel cannot open the file 'TaskMgmt.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
                        //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
                        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet in wb.Sheets)
                        {
                            if (sstext.ToLower() == sheet.Name.ToLower())
                            {
                                ssssheetname = (sheet.Name);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        wb.Close(false, missing, missing);
                        excel.Quit();
                        string query = "";
                        if (sstext == "")
                            query = "select * from [" + ssssheetname + "$]";

                        if (sstext != "")
                            query = "select * from [" + ssssheetname + "$]";

                        if (fileExt.ToLower() == ".csv")
                        {
                            if (sstext == "")
                                query = "select * from [" + Path.GetFileName(fileName) + "]";
                        }
                        OleDbDataAdapter oleAdpt = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con); //here we read data from sheet1  
                        oleAdpt.Fill(dtexcel); //fill excel data into dataTable  


                    }
                    catch (Exception ee)
                    {
                        AppendLog("excel in read inner err:" + ee.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                AppendLog("reading excel err:" + ee.ToString());
            }

            return dtexcel;

        }
```

For your understanding : I have downloaded the excel manually from this path `https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/files/my%20Files/excel%20folder` excel is downloaded successfully and able to open that excel manually with our any kind of errors and by using this method `DataTable ReadExcel_tskmgmt` I'm able to open and reading that manually downloaded excel (testing purpose I did this where my code is working or not)

And the same excel when I'm trying to download form the logic.  I'm getting this kind of error `Excel cannot open the file 'Task.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid.`

Why this error is coming?
Where I did the mistake and How to achieve this?

Note : **Logic 1 and Logic 2** both are showing the same kind of error.

Suggest me with your best solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue,

Weird one but the solution was

Solution was to download it directly on your laptop/desktop on the C:/ folder.

Had to do something with Onedrive. The folders that are being synced with onedrive i got the corrupt file issue