# Download files from SharePoint using .NET Core 6

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, sharepoint

I have been looking into online materials (mainly .NET SDKs) to help me with open SharePoint folders and download all/some of the files based on filters using .NET Core. I could see some posts with graph APIs [eg: https://blog.josephvelliah.com/download-sharepoint-file-using-microsoft-graph-api].

Is there any .NET Core 6 compatible SDK available from Microsoft to do this?

I have tried to use Graph APIs but looking for SDK from Microsoft to do this

Comment: Sharepoint's current SDK *is* Graph. There older APIs too. You don't need an SDK to download anything though, just an HTTP Get request. SharePoint is a web app and files have their own URLs

Comment: In any case there are several SO questions like [Download file from Sharepoint Online using C#.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58034425/download-file-from-sharepoint-online-using-c-net) and many Microsoft articles that show how to execute queries and retrieve files. The APIs are documented. Have you checked learn.microsoft.com?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I looked at those posts already. They are all for .Net framework  using username and password for connecting.  If no sdks then I will look more into graph APIs .

Comment: It's very frustrating. I can't seem to find a page that has code examples from A to Z. I see ones like the blog, which show everything in postman. That's great, but my users don't use Postman to access sharepoint, They want to use my web app. It would be nice to see a tutorial that goes from A to Z, describing each step.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Graph API has an SDK out of the box that works for .NET Core 6 and above. Here is a link to get you started:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet?tabs=aad

After figuring out authentication, I would recommend looking at their documentation on downloading files:

```
// To initialize your graphClient, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?from=snippets&tabs=csharp
await graphClient.Drives["{drive-id}"].Items["{driveItem-id}"].Content.GetAsync();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

Accessing SharePoint requires a SiteID and a DriveID - they are readily available when you sign-in to the Graph API Explorer:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer