# Download a File from SharePoint Online C#

Tags: c#, file, sharepoint, download, csom

Refering to: **[Download File From SharePoint 365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684101/download-file-from-sharepoint-365)**

I am using the exact same code and am getting the 401 "unauthorized" exception.

I also added the *useDefaultCredentials=True*, but no difference.

And the SharePoint.Online.CSOM is not working in .Net Core so i´m using TTCUE.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
     SharePointOnlineCredentials Creds = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password);       
     client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
     client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
     client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
     client.Credentials = Creds;
     Console.WriteLine(rootSite + sourceSite + folderSite + fileSite);
     client.DownloadFile(rootSite+sourceSite+folderSite+fileSite, destinationPath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

4 days ego there was an update on the [Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM/16.1.20211.12000) to also include .NET Standard versions. So now You may use it in .NET Core version.
Please refer to this article https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/blogs/net-standard-version-of-sharepoint-online-csom-apis/
In the movie in this blog post You may see what is the proper authentication method now that is based on tokens

hope this will be of any help